# SIGALRM implementation

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm a very beginner programmer, and i'm developing a client server program, in Ubuntu. This code belongs to my `server`file, and i want to implement a signal `SIGALRM`but i just don't know how i can do it properly. 
My goal is: in the part of the code that i'm calling the signal `alarm(ans.game_time)`, i want to run that function Time, and this function should wait `ans.game_time` seconds, and during these seconds, the players should join the game (this last part is not implemented yet, "play" command).

Estructures:

```
typedef struct request req;
struct request
{
    char str[256];
    int client_pid;
    int login; // In case of client, to identify if is logged
    int whois; // To identify who is the client and the server
};

typedef struct answer ans;
struct answer
{
    char str[256];
    int server_pid;
    int type;
    int login;
    int num_users;
    char game_name[25];
    int game_time;
    int game_users[4];
};
```

Server file:

```
#include "header"
int array_client_PID[4], num_users = 0;
int GAME_STATUS = 0;

void Time(int sign) 
{
  signal(SIGALRM, Time);
  alarm(3);
  printf("I'm Alive");
}

int main(){

    int fifo_1,fifo_2, pid, i, number_args;
    char FIFO_CLIENT[20], command[20], arg_1[20], arg_2[20];
    struct request req;
    struct answer ans;

    signal(SIGALRM, Time);

    do{ 
        read(fifo_1, &req, sizeof(req)); // Read request

            if(req.login == 1) // USER REGISTATION: If logged
                {   
                number_args = sscanf(req.str, "%s %s %s", command, arg_1, arg_2);

                    if(strcasecmp(command, "new") == 0) 
                    {
                        if(GAME_STATUS == 0) 
                        {   
                            ans.game_time = atoi(arg_2);    // Converts the string into a integrer time game
                            strcpy(ans.game_name, arg_2);   // Put the name of the game on the structure
                            ans.game_users[0] = req.client_pid; // Put on the users avaiable to play, the name of the game creator
                            alarm(ans.game_time);           
                            //CreateGame(ans); // not implemented yet

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strcpy(ans.str,"One game is in execution. Just wait...\n");
                        }                   

                    }

        if(GAME_STATUS== 1) // GAME STATUS: ON
        {
            printf("INSIDE GAME_STATUS 1\n");
            // Receive commands inside the game
        }
    }
    sprintf(FIFO_CLIENT, "FIFO_%d", req.client_pid); //2nd FIFO name with client PID
    fifo_2=open(FIFO_CLIENT, O_WRONLY); // Open 2nd FIFO to answer
    write(fifo_2, &ans, sizeof(ans)); // Write an answer

    }while(1);
}
```

I tried to understand how it works properly, but this signal is really confusing for me.

Comment: Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). You probably want to `poll`. See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: As @BasileStarynkevitch implies, you shouldn't use signals for this at all.  Using signals properly is no task for a beginning programmer, and it shouldn't be needed for most applications.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I really need to use signals in this part of the code, my professor said that is mandatory.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Actually signals are not new for me, but this specific one, it's pretty hard to understand how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the ALARM (ALRM) signal goes off you are most likely waiting in the `read(fifo_1 ...);` call, but you do not handle this case.

```
if (read(fifo_1, ...) == -1) {
    /* some error occurred in the read... */
    if (errno == EINTR) {
        /* error was interruption, most likely by the ALARM */
        /* handle this in whatever way is appropriate */
    }
}
```

Refining some more, almost always, it is best practice to do as little as possible in a signal handler -- typically, just setting a flag that says the signal happened.

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t alarms_happened = 0;
static sig_atomic_t alarms_handled = 0;

static void Time ( int signo ) {
    if (signo == SIGALRM) alarms_happened++;
}
```

then in your main loop wherever you are prepared to handle the alarm:

```
if (alarms_happened != alarms_handled) {
    alarms_handled = alarms_happened;
    /* do whatever you need to do when there was an alarm */
}
```

Comment: FYI, *volatile* means a variable can be changed outside the normal program flow -- it basically tells the compiler that some optimizations would be incorrect because its assumptions could be wrong.  And *sig_atomic_t* is an integer of a size/alignment that the system guarantees can be updated *'atomically*' (all at once) -- so that it can't possibly be seen partially updated.

Comment: ohh, i didn't think about it like this way! Thank's for the time, it will be really useful!

Answer (score 3):

`alarm()` is not a good way to implement periodic events in a server. It functions as an asynchronous signal, and as such is difficult to handle appropriately while something else is going on. For instance, if your server is in the middle of sending a message to a client, having the alarm go off and start generating output would be likely to disrupt the message. Bottom line is, it's not the right way of going about this.

Most client/server applications use the `select()` or `poll()` system calls at their core. These system calls allow your application to wait for an event to occur (e.g, data arriving) on any number of file descriptors, with an optional timeout. This is how most server applications handle connections with multiple clients at a time.

Using these system calls is likely to require you to restructure your application around a "state machine" model, rather than using program flow to represent state. Explaining how to do this effectively is a larger task than is reasonable for a short answer such as this; prepare to do some research!

Comment: Hello. Thanks in advance for the tip, but i really need to use signals to do this part of the program.
In the `do{}while` circle, i'm not showing every code,  i'm reading and writing to the server clients a lot of times, and i just can't stop in one function, and leave all of the clients waiting. I think that this is the reason that i need to use signals, to do two things at the same time, moreover my professor asks specifically to use signals in this part.

Comment: If you're writing this program as part of a class assignment, please contact your professor for support. While you're at it… please direct him to this answer, with a reminder that many system calls and library functions are **not** safe to use in signal handlers.